# Where is the definition of __NR_accept?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, system-calls

As I known, the syscall numbers' definitions are in the format of __NR_xxxx in asm/unistd.h, but I cannot find the definition of __NR_accept, Why?

Comment: for which architecture you are looking, in arm it is #define __NR_accept   (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+285)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On many architectures, the accept system call number *is* in `<asm/unistd.h>`.

However, I suspect you're asking about i386 or another "older" architecture.  In that case, for historical reasons, there isn't really an `accept` system call -- instead, one uses the multiplexed [`socketcall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketcall.2.html) system call with a call number of `SYS_ACCEPT` to perform `accept()`.  You *will* find a definition of `__NR_socketcall` in your `<asm/unistd.h>` (and definitions of `SYS_SOCKET`, `SYS_BIND`, `SYS_CONNECT`, `SYS_LISTEN`, `SYS_ACCEPT` and so on in `<linux/net.h>` for the various socket-related system calls that are multiplexed through `socketcall`).

In any case, for architectures where there is no true `accept` system call, you will of course also not have a system call number `__NR_accept`.